# Find the convergence and the limit of the sequence : $x_{n}=\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\sqrt{...a\sqrt{a}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the convergence  and the limit of the sequence: $x_{n}=\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\sqrt{...a\sqrt{a}}}}$ (with n square root sign 2)

---

My idea:
We can rewrite $x_{n}=\sqrt{a{x_{n-1}}}$.

Then, let consider two cases that $a>1$ and $0<a<1$. From this, I don not know how to illustrate clearly when the sequence increase or decrease. Especially, I want to see the inductive method. Please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: If $a>1$ try proving $x_n<a$ otherwise ($0<a<1$) try proving $x_n>a$

Comment: A way of seeing the pattern mentioned below is to write it (for $n=3$) as $\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\sqrt{a}}} =a^{\frac{1}{2}}a^{\frac{1}{4}}a^{\frac{1}{8}} = a^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3}}$. From this you hopefully see the pattern and if you don't you can atleast see that we should have $x_n = a^{y_n}$ for some "simple" fraction $y_n$. Taking this as an ansatz you can derive a simple linear recursion relation for $y_n$ which is solved by standard methods.

Comment: @kingW3 Please explain more for me. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to prove what I said? Induction with $x_n=\sqrt{ax_{n-1}}$ should be pretty straightforward, if you still fail ping me again.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Show by induction that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$
$$a_n = a^{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}$$